# EventActivityIdControl API to get co-relation id is not working in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

Overview:
We have implemented a real time virus scanner for SharePoint by implementing the IMSO_VirusScanner COM interface. We are looking for the Correlation Id (Guid) for each request, to IMSO_VirusScanner methods using the below Win32 API

SharePoint versions:
SharePoint 2010

OS:
All supported OS for that SharePoint platform.

Win32 API:
EventActivityIdControl
Ref: - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363720(v=vs.85).aspx

Background:
When the Scan and Clean methods of IMSO_VirusScanner get called by SharePoint, some information about the document is received via arguments to these methods. However we are looking for the Correlation Id from the above Win32API in the Scan and Clean methods for each request. This API works in SharePoint 2010 for other methods of IMSO_VirusScanner such as Initialize but did not work for methods such as Scan & Clean.

Observations:
The above Win32 API works fine in these scenarios for SharePoint 2013.

Comment: Please reply to my question.